# text extraction from a file and convert to json format

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I am tackling quite a complex text extraction with set of rules and convert it into json format. Any help is highly appreciated.

The rules are as below:

1. If the line contains string and next line has only numbers like "1, 2,. .." etc, then that line is the key and following lines are going to be the values and should start appending the values (E.g. Introduction as key)
2. Sometimes, the value line starts with numbers also. (E.g. 5. Expected results are stored here) These lines will also be appended to values(After removing the starting digit)
3. The values can also be subdivided as a., b. etc. These should be treated as values also. If the line has only "a, b, c" etc., then the next line is considered value and should be appended to the value
4. For example Helloworld2 is the value and the next line Expected Results is the key as it's next line has only digits/number as 6

```html
Introduction
1.
Hello and welcome to the world
2. GDPR requires companies to have technical and organizational measures in place. With Drata’s 24/7 monitoring, you eliminate manual processes like reviewing dozens of systems.
3 
GDPR requires companies to have technical and organizational measures in place. With Drata’s 24/7 monitoring, you eliminate manual processes like reviewing dozens of systems. 
4. The sky is so high:
    a. 
Hello world1
    b. 
Helloworld2
Expected Results
5. Expected results are stored here
6
This is a highly complex issue to be resolved
```

My expected output is as below:

Expected output as below:

```
[
    {
        "key" : "Introduction",
        "value" : "Hello and welcome to the world. GDPR requires companies to have technical and organizational measures in place. With Drata’s 24/7 monitoring, you eliminate manual processes like reviewing dozens of systems. GDPR requires companies to have technical and organizational measures in place. With Drata’s 24/7 monitoring, you eliminate manual processes like reviewing dozens of systems. The sky is so high: Hello world1  Helloworld2"
    }
    {
        "key" : "Expected Results",
        "value" : "Expected results are stored here. This is a highly complex issue to be resolved"
    
    }

]
```

Comment: Where is your attempted solution? SO isn't a code-writing service. What ***specific*** programming problem do you need help with?

Comment: I am working on python. As the logic is bit complex,  I am struck at checking one line and next line at the same time.